# How to change p-value stars cutoff in export_summs (R)

Tags: r

In export_summs function, the default stars cutoff is:
 *** p < 0.001 ; ** p < 0.01 ; * p < 0.05.

I would like to change it to:
 *** p < 0.01 ; ** p < 0.05 ; * p < 0.1.

But I can't seem to figure out how exactly.

Here is my code:

```
export_summs(Fixed_effects1, Random_effects1, Fixed_effects2, Random_effects2, 
             scale = TRUE, 
             model.names = c("(Market1) Fixed effects","(Market1) Random effects","(Market2) Fixed effects","(Market2) Random effects"), 
             statistics = c(N = "nobs", R2 = "r.squared") , 
             coefs = c("Constant" = "(Intercept)", 
                       "Periodtrend" = "p_trend", "Markettrend" = "m_trend"), 
             error_format = "({p.value})")
```

Thank you.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example along with the package names

Comment: Sorry. This is the jtools package: export_summs(Fixed_effects1, Random_effects1, Fixed_effects2,Random_effects2,scale = TRUE,
             model.names = c("(Market1) Fixed effects","(Market1) Random effects","(Market2) Fixed effects","(Market2) Random effects"),
             statistics = c(N = "nobs", R2 = "r.squared") , coefs =  c("Constant" = "(Intercept)", "Periodtrend" = "p_trend",
"Markettrend" = "m_trend"),error_format = "({p.value})")

Comment: The convention for p < 0.1 is noted with ·, not *. I don't think it's advisable to change these standard notation in public writings because it is misleading.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I still preferred it changed.

Comment: Worth pointing out that the * = 0.1 convention has become established in economics. I think it's a terrible idea, but sometimes you have to go with reviewers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `export_summs()` from package `jtools` relies heavily on `huxreg()` from package `huxtable` therefore you can simply pass the argument `stars` inside `export_summs()` to acheive the desired result:

```
export_summs(...,
             stars = c(`***` = 0.01, `**` = 0.05, `*` = 0.1)
            )
```

As I pointed out in my comment, changing these standard notations can be misleading for others as well as your future self.